# Traffic flow with and without VPN?

Tags: networking, vpn

I was not able to access an open learning website that was working fine earlier with the same **Vodafone** network.

To troubleshoot this further I have checked it with another network **JIO** and found that It is working fine.

So, further, I checked with the Vodafone network by connecting VPN and found that It is working as expected. (If I am disconnecting VPN then It's not working).

**FYI:**
a)Without VPN with Vodafone Network

```
(base) Shailesh-Yadav:~ shaileshyadaav$ host website_name
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

b)after connecting VPN with Vodafone network

```
shaileshyadaav$ host website_name
www.web_site_name is an alias for spayeeservers.com.
spayeeservers.com has address 134.2XX.XX.XX
spayeeservers.com mail is handled by 0 smtp.secureserver.net.
```

It'll be very much helpful to understand working if anyone can help me with below question.

**1**. I am accessing an open website(not having any restriction) and the same is not accessible with the **Vodafone** network but observe that It's working when I am connected to **VPN**. So how the traffic is flowing.

**2**.Any command through which I can understand the destination route(how it is reaching) OR differentiate the flow path(reason for this).

Answer (score 0):

I have checked it by using the `traceroute` command and found that the traffic is flowing with different routes(hopes) with VPN and without VPN.
So, It means if we are connected to VPN then all the traffic will go through a tunnel and the site is not working without a **VPN** maybe some restriction from the ISP side.
(but again one doubt which one is better/faster in performance).